# Работа с изображениями python

Tags: python, изображения

Python как генерировать изображения такого типа

У меня есть несколько строк и мне из них надо сгенерировать вот такое изображение

[image]

Как мне реализовать это?

Comment: а зачем вам это нужно?

Comment: PIL  в помощь, библиотека для работы с изображениями.

Comment: pip install pillow

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Пример использования библиотеки PIL*

```
#Импорт необходимых модулей
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont


def main():
    #Создаём новое изображение
    image = Image.new('RGB', (300, 200), color=('gray'))
    #Объект для рисования
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    #Загружаем шрифт
    font = ImageFont.truetype("pt-sans.ttf", 17)
    #Рисуем текст
    draw.text((0, 0),"Пример для работы с библиотекой PIL", (0, 255, 255),font=font)
    #Сохраняем изображение
    image.save('example-text.jpg')
    #Показать изображение
    image.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[Документация Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: Шрифт скачайте, который вам необходим.

Comment: Большое спасибо работает, я вам правда благодарен, поскольку это единственный мой вопрос, в котором я не был уверен с точки зрения возможности реализации

Comment: Пожалуйста, удачи вам!

Comment: Кстати можете отметить как ответ на вопрос) Есть специальная кнопка.

Comment: Лучше поздно, чем никогда)